# Another way to say "work against each other"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I need to say that two things "work against each other," but I want to say it in a more formal way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: How about saying that they counteract one another?

Comment: _at odds_ and _in conflict_ might work. Could you provide more context?

Comment: What are working against each other? Why do you think they are not formal?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I think that in conflict is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: We don't encourage a question without context. This community is not your thesaurus. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

So you'd have : **opposite ; contradictory ; in opposition**

Comment: Sorry ! I forgot : ANTAGONIST....

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is looking out for the word **Internecine**.

Webster's dictionary defines internecine as,

```
of, relating to, or involving conflict within a group
```

and it is destructive to both sides involved in the conflict.

Comment: Hi, Nagarajan, we don't have any context and the question is unclear. We don't even know whether the Original Poster is looking for a verb or noun.